# How many words can you make with {1,2,3,4} such that difference between 2 letters is 1

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

Hello and happy new year.

I've been struggling with this question and I really need some help.

The question is, find a recurrence relation that demonstrates how many words of length $n$ can we write with the letters $\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that the difference between 2 adjacent letters is 1?

For example, 121232 is valid

121323 is not.

Clarification: I'm not asking for a direct answer. I'm looking for something like $f(n) = f(n-1)+2f(n-2)$, where $f(n)$ represents the number of valid words of length $n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hint:

Denote by $f(n)$ the number of words of length $n$ ending in $2$ or $3$, and by $g(n)$ the number of words of length $n$ ending in $1$ or $4$. Then
$$f(n+1)=g(n)+f(n),\quad g(n+1)=f(n)\ .$$